# Highest Average in SQL Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, max, average

I have to write an SQL for the question "What is the song by the Stokes with the highest average rating?"
I get stuck on the fact that I have to display the maximum average. I now have this:

```
SELECT STitle
FROM Songs S, Like L, Perform P, Artists A
WHERE S.SId=L.SId
AND P.AId=A.AId
AND S.SId=P.SId
AND AName="The Stokes"
AND Rating=(
SELECT Max (Rating) as "Highest rating", AVG(Rating) as "average rating"
FROM Songs S, Like L
WHERE S.SId=L.SId
Group BY S.SId, STitle);
```

I hope one of you can get it, cause I've been stuck on it for a while now. 
Thanks everyone! :)

[The Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHhM1.jpg)

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PT4m.jpg)

Comment: If you are learning SQL, learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Only use commas in the `FROM` clause because MS Access doesn't support `CROSS JOIN` explicitly.

Comment: I can't believe someone put up an assignment where `LIKE` is a table name. Next time you should ask innocently whether it's a good idea to use a reserved word for that.

Comment: I think you need to first calculate the AVG rating (inner subquery), then the MAX from that (outer subquery).

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 sid, avg(rating) from songs 
   join [like] on [like].sid = songs.sid
   join perform on perform.sid = songs.sid
   join compose on compose.sid = songs.sid
   join artists on perform.aid = artists.aid
 where artists.aname = "The Stokes"
 group by artists.aid 
 order by avg(rating) desc
```

Without the tables I'm not sure this will work. I usually have to futz around a bit but it should get you in the right direction